# Facing java.net.SocketTimeoutException using mobilefirst 6.3 for hybrid app

Tags: android, exception, timeout, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a hybrid application using MF 6.3. I am facing a java socket timeout issue while I request data through
adapter. This is not consistent. It happens 3-4/10 times. I have also
seen the same issue mentioned in github
https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/issues/146 but with
no resolution.

I am using the adapter timeout of 60 seconds, and this exception occurs within 10 seconds.

Attaching the logcat for logs.

> 09-18 15:07:29.561: I/System.out(10667): pool-6-thread-2 calls
>   detatch()
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.146: I/System.out(10667): pool-6-thread-5 calls
>   detatch()
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):
>   WLNativeXHRPlugin$NativeXHRPostListener.onException in
>   WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:154 :: onException
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:728)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1351)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:700)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:691)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:514)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   com.worklight.wlclient.WLHybridRequestSender.run(WLHybridRequestSender.java:63)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.166:
>   E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10667):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>
> 09-18 15:07:39.176: E/NONE(10667):
>   [/apps/services/api/SCBBizNet/android/query] Host is not responsive.
>   Try to manually access the URL through the android emulator browser to
>   verify connectivity.

Comment: Where is the adapter request going?

Comment: I am calling a java web service via adapter returning the result in json format.

Comment: Use Wireshark to collect network traffic logs from success and failure attempts. Lets see what the network tells us.

Comment: The scenario comes on mobile devices only. I am using Samsung Galaxy S4. How to proceed in this case?

Comment: As instructed. Install Wireshark on the host machine where the server is install and observe network traffic during failure and success for the specific port you're using.

Comment: As the server is installed on host machine at the client side, it would require all sorts of permission to install tools like wireshark at their end which is pretty difficult. They may not allow.

Comment: If the customer wants this further investigated, this is my current assumption. The network needs to be inspected.

Comment: I am quite skeptical as this step may or may not work as it would require all business justification and a security threat from their perspective as it involves high risk data leak. I would give it a try but it would take considerable amount of time. Is their any other alternative in the mean time.

Comment: Does it happen also in the QA environment or only production environment? If it happens only in the latter then you need to check your network. Something is not letting requests to pass.

Comment: Waiting to hear if this is also reproducible in an internal testing environment where network inspection could be performed.

Comment: Yes this is reproducible in the DEV , SIT and UAT envs. As all the servers are present at the client location so it wud take a bit of time for wireshark installation to inspect. I am looking for some other alternatives to start debug atleast to trace. Is there any other approach to follow  as this exception doesn't get caught in adapter layer.

Comment: Trace and Wireshark should help.

Comment: Client disagreed for installing the Wireshark on dev server. As of now we are tracing the logs on MF server but no luck as of now.

Comment: What about a trace.log?

Comment: A separate team is still working on this issue.

Comment: ajay, please bring a representative of this team to here. Need an update.

Comment: Resolved! We are calling the WL.Logger.send() for sending logs inside $.getJson which loads configuration json file based on sends logs. After this step we come out of the $.getJson callback and calls adapter for page load. The entire event is happening on button click. If we remove $.getJson and call WL.Logger.send() it does not give Socket time out exception. However this problem appears to be quite unusual as after calling the WL.Logger.send() inside $.getJson and the subsequent adapter call fails 5-6 times out of 10 times giving socket Timeout exception which is beyond the adapter layer.

Comment: ajay, please write this as an answer to the question and not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved! 
We are calling the `WL.Logger.send()` for sending logs inside `$.getJson` which loads the configuration json file based on which we send logs to the server. After this step we come out of the `$.getJson` callback and calls the adapter to load the page with data. The entire event is happening on a button click. If we remove `$.getJson` and call `WL.Logger.send()` it does not give any Socket time out exception.

However this problem appears to be quite unusual as after calling the `WL.Logger.send()` inside `$.getJson` and the subsequent adapter call fails 5-6 times out of 10 times giving socket Timeout exception which is beyond the adapter layer. This exception is more frequent in android and less in iOS. We are further investigating the problem caused by `$.getJson`. Will post the update.

Comment: Any news about this?

Comment: Got it solved too... I had a sequence of uploading Data to MFP server, starting another upload (images) when this resolved from its promise while the Angular JS app changed pages and more read requests were issued towards the MFP. Somehow this might have gotten the Client into a deadlock of some sort, causing the timeout. My solution was to not call the function to upload the images directly from the resolve function but use an internal event to trigger the upload. Which worked flawlessly.